# How to get a BuildContext from WidgetTester?

Tags: flutter-test

When doing a Flutter widget test, I can get a context from the `WidgetTester` if I know something about at least one widget in the tree. E.g., if I know there's a `Text` widget in the test widget tree, I can

```
BuildContext context = tester.element(find.byType(Text));
```

How can I get a context more generally? E.g., can I get the root widget of the tree and get its `BuildContext`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a `navigatorKey` using

```dart
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

Assign this `navigatorKey` to your material app widget in your test class.

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(
  MaterialApp(
    home: const Scaffold(),
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  ),
);
```

Then you will be able to access its context using `navigatorKey.currentContext`.

Note that there must be a widget in the tree (in this case a `Scaffold`) otherwise `navigatorKey.currentContext` will be `null`.

Comment: I am not very happy with this answer: it is basically what already has been suggested in the question: acquiring the buildContext from some part of the UI-Widget. Isn't there a cleaner way?

A way that does not require us to alter the UI/Widget?

Comment: I think the answer in the question is better than the actual answer for most cases.